# how to create function to repeat a vector in a list n times?

Tags: kdb

I have the following vector:

```
 v:(1,-1)
```

I would like to create a function that repeats this vector in a list n times example:

```
f[v,3] results in ((1 -1);(1 -1);(1 -1))
```

Can someone help me define this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [# take](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#take) function for this, e.g.

```
q)f:{y#enlist x}

q)f[v;3]
1 -1
1 -1
1 -1
```

It can also be done without enlisting the vector, e.g.

```
q)3 2#v
1 -1
1 -1
1 -1
```

Or more generally:

```
q)f:{(y;count x)#x}
q)f[v;3]
1 -1
1 -1
1 -1
```

Comment: This results in  list (1 -1;1 -1;1 -1) is there a difference with this list ((1 -1);(1 -1);(1 -1)) in q? I am applying a function to f(v) and the input seems to need the extra brackets or I get an error. If the above two lists are equivalent than my problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Both are same, you can compare it with binary compare operator (`~`) -             `q)(1 -1;1 -1;1 -1)~((1 -1);(1 -1);(1 -1))`

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this if you don't want to create a new function:

```
q)#[3;enlist v]
1 -1
1 -1
1 -1
```